# java.sql.SQLException: Login failed for user

Tags: sql-server, hibernate

I'm trying to configure Hibernate to connect to MS SQL Server 2005 Management Studio Express, but I can't login. I have searched everywhere for a solution, but cant find anything that I can find helpful.

I know the password and username are correct, but they dont seem to work. If anyone can help, I would appreciate it.

This is my configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
  <!-- Database connection settings -->
  <property name="connection.driver_class">net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="connection.url">jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://***********/**********; databaseName=Scores</property>
  <property name="connection.username">*****</property>
  <property name="connection.password">******</property>

  <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
  <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

  <!-- SQL dialect -->
  <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>

  <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
  <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

  <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
  <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

  <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>

  <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
  <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

  <!-- Mapping files -->
  <mapping resource="player.hbm.xml"/>

 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

This is the output (Its very long, so I have included a small part of it)

```
50 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.3.2.GA
54 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - hibernate.properties not found
59 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : javassist
83 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
278 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
278 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
1373 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Reading mappings from resource : player.hbm.xml
1480 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder - Mapping class: database.Player -> users
1525 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configured SessionFactory: null
1697 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
1697 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - Hibernate connection pool size: 1
1697 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - autocommit mode: false
1700 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - using driver: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver at URL: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://    50 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.3.2.GA
54 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - hibernate.properties not found
59 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : javassist
83 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
278 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
278 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
1373 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Reading mappings from resource : player.hbm.xml
1480 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder - Mapping class: database.Player -> users
1525 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configured SessionFactory: null
1697 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
1697 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - Hibernate connection pool size: 1
1697 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - autocommit mode: false
1700 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - using driver: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver at URL: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://********-PC/*********; databaseName=Scores
1700 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - connection properties: {user=****, password=****}
2169 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] WARN org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Could not obtain connection to query metadata
java.sql.SQLException: Login failed for user '****'.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:372)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2893)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2335)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.login(TdsCore.java:609)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:369)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:183)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source); databaseName=Scores
1700 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - connection properties: {user=****, password=****}
2169 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] WARN org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Could not obtain connection to query metadata
java.sql.SQLException: Login failed for user '****'.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:372)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2893)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2335)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.login(TdsCore.java:609)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:369)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:183)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
```

---

```
3293 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - could not complete schema update
java.sql.SQLException: Login failed for user '*****'.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:372)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2893)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2335)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.login(TdsCore.java:609)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:369)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:183)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
```

---

```
3447 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 18456, SQLState: 28000
3447 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Login failed for user '*****'.
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1354)
    at database.ScoreDB.addPlayerScore(ScoreDB.java:17)
```

Comment: You config says databaseName=names but your error says databaseName=Scores, are you picking up the right config?

Comment: Thats been changed, the config file now reads databaseName=Scores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try another driver and check if it works, maybe. I use this one and it works:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

To connect:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://SERVER[\\INSTANCE];DatabaseName=dbname
```

If still not working, check if you missed any config or something it's bad spelled, but seems that it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just one question, is the instance name necessary? The name in asterisks is only a name, there is no instance name specified.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know if is needed, but I think yes. If you connect to your database with SQL Management Studio and you use something like //LOCALHOST\INSTANCENAME\ and all works fine, try using it if you never did it.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms378428(v=sql.90).aspx
It says that it is optional, but it will use a default instance name. As I said, if you use an instance to connect via SQL Management Studio and it works, I suggest you to try using the same instance name.

Comment: It worked! Think it was changing the driver, but not sure. Could also have been a mistake in the connection url. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome! ^^ I'm happy that it works. Have a good day.